# Hiding the label

Tags: html, css, input, label

I would like to disable or hide the contents "Grouping" 
of `<label>` tag without affecting the nested `<input>` tag.

```
<label class="" for="officersheet_fields_attributes_3_grouping">
<input type="checkbox" id="officersheet_fields_attributes_3_grouping" name="officersheet[fields_attributes][3][grouping]" value="1">
Grouping
</label>`
```

I am using formtastic within rails.
formtastic code snippet 
`<td><%= f.input :grouping  %></td>`

the above line generates the html above.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You may use `text-indent: -1000em`.

```
label
{
    text-indent: -1000em;
}
```

But I don't think it is a good idea to have the input inside the label. Better have following:

```
<input type="checkbox"/><label>Grouping</label>
```

Comment: What's wrong with placing the `input` inside the `label`? The W3C says that the `label` can be placed before, after or around an `input` > http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#edef-LABEL

Comment: the issue is that it is generated automatically by formtastic in rails. code `<td><%= f.input :grouping  %></td>`

Comment: Of course it is possible, and it is valid too. But a label is the clickable text for a input control. To place the input control inside is not very clean I think. Besides, you are more flexible when you seperate them.

Comment: Thanks Linus Caldwell , BenM

Answer (score 0):

Add `span` tag around the label text and hide it

```
<label for="foo">
    <input type="checkbox" value="1"><span>Grouping</span>
</label>
```

CSS

```
span{
    display:none 
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/CmHRm/1/)**

Answer (score 0):

I would go for the span too, but if you have no control on your html structure, you could do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('label')
      .contents() 
      .each(function() { 
          // if (this.nodeType == Node.TEXT_NODE);  this works unless using IE 7
          if (this.nodeType === 3) {
              $(this).remove();
          }
      });
});
```